# Using `\headsep` with the geometry and fanchyhdr packages

Tags: header-footer, geometry

I thought that the text on the page was supposed to start `\headsep` below the header, but that does not seem to be the case when I use the `geometry` and `fancyhdr` packages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{foo}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}\fancyhead[L]{\hrulefill\hspace{\fill}}}
\pagestyle{foo}
\geometry{includeall, vmargin=0pt, headheight=\baselineskip, headsep=72pt}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{-\headsep}\hrulefill\par
\vspace{\fill}
\end{document}
```

How much `\vspace` needs to be added so that the `\hrulefill` in the body lines up with the fanchyhdr rule? What about so the `\hrulefill` in the body lines up with the rule in `\fancyhead[L]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hrulefill` (unlike `\hrule`) starts a paragraph so you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{foo}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}\fancyhead[L]{\hrulefill\hspace{\fill}}}
\pagestyle{foo}
\geometry{includeall, vmargin=0pt, headheight=\baselineskip, headsep=72pt}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topskip-\headsep-\baselineskip+0.4pt\relax}\hrulefill\par
\vspace{\fill}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also apparently need a `\topskip` and an extra 0.4 pt for the rule itself.